# googleVis html generated from r not working on Chrome

Tags: r, google-chrome, googlevis

I am using googleVis package in r to create google graphs, its working as expected in IE and Mozilla but not working in Chrome, all the html coming in source code but not appearing on page

```
M <-  gvisMotionChart(Fruits, "Fruit", "Year", options = list(width=600, height=400))
plot(M)
```

I am using Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit) for Chorme, Please let me know if I am missing anything.